# Add value from one table to another, depending on dates

Tags: sql

how can i add a value from one table to another. There is a attribute(VALUE) that depends on the date from both tables. So VALUE has to get add to TABLE 1 between the corret dates.

Example:

Table 1

```
ID   BEGIN         END      MODEL DOLLAR
1   2014-01-01  2014-01-31   Z5      500
1   2014-02-01  2014-02-28   Z5      500
1   2014-03-01  2014-03-31   Z5      672
1   2014-03-11  2014-03-31   Z3      158
1   2014-04-01  2014-04-30   Z3      023
....
1   2016-12-01  2016-12-31   Z2     400
1   2017-01-01  2017-01-31   Z4     433
1   2017-02-01  2017-02-28   Z9     065
```

Table 2

```
ID   BEGIN         END      VALUE    
1   2014-01-01  2017-01-01   3
1   2017-01-01  2999-12-31   9
```

This is a small example from 2 big tables. I discovered that the join works, but sometimes some errors occurs(because sum(dollar) isnt 100% right). Do i have to add something in the join clause?

```
select * from t1
INNER JOIN t2 on 
(
t1.id = t2.id
and t1.begin between t2.beginn and t1.begin 
and t1.end between t1.end and t2.end
)

DESIRED RESULT

ID   BEGIN         END      MODEL DOLLAR  VALUE
1   2014-01-01  2014-01-31   Z5      500      3
1   2014-02-01  2014-02-28   Z5      500      3
1   2014-03-01  2014-03-31   Z5      672      3
1   2014-03-11  2014-03-31   Z3      158      3
1   2014-04-01  2014-04-30   Z3      023      3
...
1   2016-12-01  2016-12-31   Z2     400       3
1   2017-01-01  2017-01-31   Z4     433       9
1   2017-02-01  2017-02-28   Z9     065       9
```

Comment: It makes no sense to say that a value is between another value and itself. You just could use a `WHERE t2.begin > t1.begin  AND t2.end > t1.end` clause after the `JOIN`.

Comment: Maybe make `t2` a `select ... from table1 where ... UNION select ... from table2 where ...`, adjusting the `where` clauses to cover the correct data ranges.

Comment: `sometimes some errors occurs`. Could you please indicate what happens in these cases?

Comment: I suppose your (weird) join-clause wants to make sure that the period in table 1 is completely covered by the period in table 2. If so, please change into `... AND t1.begin >= t2.begin AND t1.end <= t2.end`

Comment: What happens if both begin and end in table 1 are 2017-01-01? In that case both records in table 2 match

Comment: You are right, table 1 period needs to be covered by table 2. Now i have 4 solutions, but the problem is, that i am getting some duplicates. I checked many IDs and never hit a duplicate, always works fine, but i see on the sum that i get a little bit to much dollars.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: Oh now i see what´s the problem, the data isn´t always correct. The begin and end dates moves sometimes over years, but should just run over a month. No chance to correct that for now, but thxs all for your help. Gordons full overlap will do it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want any overlap, then:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2 
     on t1.id = t2.id and
        t2.begin <= t1.end
        t2.end >= t1.begin;
```

If you want *full overlap* then:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2 
     on t1.id = t2.id and
        t2.begin <= t1.begin
        t2.end >= t1.end;
```

Note:  Because you are dealing with time ranges, you may get multiple matches in the result set for a single time frame.

Comment: That´s the problem, im getting some duplicates, but not too many. Hard to find them...

Comment: @HellaF10 . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do when two (or more) time frames from one table overlap with one from the other.